# Why is diez character over the keyboard not recongised?

Tags: characters

I just started to use ubuntu 12.10. I wonder why my characters over the keyboard are not recognised as they are written on it. For example I press Shift+3 and I get this character  £ instead of diez that I need .It is pretty inconvenient. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Your physical keyboard paint job and layout does not match what the OS thinks it is. Your OS probably thinks you're British, but your keyboard is designed for somewhere else. If you teach your OS what keyboard you actually have, it should improve. [This](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu) might help.

Comment: What is "diez"?